# Display ProgressBar while dynamically loading GridPane

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

Heyyo,

So I'm currently working on a JavaFX project, with another Java project handling/serving the data for said project.

While I got most things working, I am still trying to get a ProgressBar to load while loading the data from the data project, which I am having some issues doing.

Currently, I'm looping through the data, creating/adding labels to a GridPane for each "entry". Above it, I declare a JavaFX ProgressBar and add it to my "root wrapper" `VBox`.

```
            GridPane wrapper = new GridPane();
            ProgressBar progress = new ProgressBar();    
            viewBox.getChildren().add(progress);           

            int currentRow = 1;     
            for(Map.Entry<String, List<Observation>> item : handler.get(from, to).entrySet()) {                    
                if(item != null) {
                    for(Observation inner : item.getValue()) {
                        if(inner != null) {
                            // Add the data for the datalist
                            wrapper.add(new Label(item.getKey()), 0, currentRow);
                            wrapper.add(new Label(inner.getDate().toString()), 1, currentRow);
                            wrapper.add(new Label(String.valueOf(inner.getValue())), 2, currentRow);

                            currentRow++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            viewBox.getChildren().add(wrapper);
```

Now, to the things I have tried to achieve this, as I realise this code alone won't do much:

1) Tried wrapping the GridPane in a `Task` and creating a new thread from said task - Didn't work due to trying to create JavaFX elements while not being in the JavaFX Application Thread

2) Tried wrapping all of the `wrapper.add(new Label(...));`  in `Platform.runLater()` - As `wrapper` is not final and needs to exist both inside and outside of the scope, this did not work either.

3) Tried adding the data entry-by-entry to a temporary map and showing the progress that way by letting the ProgressBar-part run in it's own Task/Thread. Seemed to work as long as I used `Thread.join();` afterwards, but seems extremely ineffective.

As always, any and all help is appreciated. If I forgot to mention something required to be able to tell what's going on, please do let me know! I've tried to include everything relevant.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you want to update a progressbar every time a "data" has been loaded? You should also show whether the code above is on the application thread or not.

Comment: I want a progressbar that loads and "finishes" when the loop on the 6th row is finished, is a way to put it I guess. The code snippet is all currently in the application thread. @Andreas

Comment: Regarding "1)", there are only a few JavaFX GUI objects that must be created on the FX thread; most of the objects are capable of being created _and_ modified (so long as they aren't part of a scene-graph) on any single thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you've created your progressbar and it shows up on your GUI use

```
progress.setProgress(double value)
```

with an appropriate value depending on how far you've come in your progress.

As an example, you could put the progress like following:

```
progress.setProgress((currentRow - 1) / handler.get(from, to).entrySet().size())
```

This line can be put as first line in your for loop. When the whole job is done set the progress to 1 or remove the progress bar.

Comment: Seems to be working, however also seem to be having some other unexpected errors. Still, answers the question so i'll mark it as the answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Nodes can be created in any thread, but you must not add them to a scene from a background thread. You shouldn't update properties of nodes in a scene from a background thread either.

```
GridPane wrapper = new GridPane();
ProgressBar progress = new ProgressBar();
viewBox.getChildren().add(progress);
viewBox.getChildren().add(wrapper);

new Thread(() -> {
    Collection<Map.Entry<String, List<Observation>>> entries = handler.get(from, to).entrySet();
    final double totalEntries = entries.size();
    int currentRow = 1; 
    for(Map.Entry<String, List<Observation>> item : entries) {                    
        if(item != null) {
            for(Observation inner : item.getValue()) {
                if(inner != null) {
                    // Add the data for the datalist
                    final Node[] nds = new Node[] {
                        new Label(item.getKey()),
                        new Label(inner.getDate().toString()),
                        new Label(new Label(String.valueOf(inner.getValue())))
                    };
                    final double newProgress = currentRow / totalEntries;
                    final int r = currentRow;
                    Platform.runLater(() -> {
                        wrapper.addRow(r, nds);
                        progress.setProgress(newProgress);
                    });
                    currentRow++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}).start();
```